# How do you install the unit test generator extension in Visual Studio 2013 express

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Ways of doing this that don't work

'tools' -> 'Extensions and Updates...' and search for it and press download. - The problem with this is it doesn't come up with a unit test generator option.

Download it from http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/45208924-e7b0-45df-8cff-165b505a38d7 then double click on the download, which auto installs it. - Unfortunately double clicking does nothing, I then installed a zip extractor (the file is a renamed zip file), but that didn't help.

download it, then 'tools' -> 'extensions manager'. - There is no extensions manager option.

There is no extensions folder in the visual studio 2013 folder, but I tried pasting the folder (zipped and unzipped) and the contents in the packages folder.

This is what the unzipped folder looks like [image: inside]

Comment: I'm not sure if this question belongs here, but I didn't know what other site to post it to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio Express does not support 3rd party extensions. Even though this was produced by the VS Rangers it's still considered 3rd party.

> Willy-P. Schaub - 
>   The Unit Test Generator extension is supported on Visual Studio Pro, Premium and Ultimate. We do not currently support VS Express.

From the [extension's Q & A Tab](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/45208924-e7b0-45df-8cff-165b505a38d7)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'd forgotten about this question. 
 
Being considered 3rd party was a bit confusing.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it on VS 2013 Ultimate, if you have a different edition, it may be missing some options, but I would assume something like Extensions should follow the same process

Go to Tools -> Extensions & Updates -> Online
Search Unit Test Generator, should be top one I think
Click Download
After Download completes accept License and hit Install
Click on Restart Visual Studio on the bottom right of the Extension Manager Window

Comment: This is what I'm doing but it doesn't come up when I search for unit test generator. I am using VS 2013 express, so that is probably the issue.

Comment: Hmm there is definitely something wrong there. it seems almost as if  you're somehow locked out of the repo, that's strange

Comment: Yes it will work with Ultimate. Extensions are restricted based on the extension author and VS SKU. See my answer below.